# Change the color of the highlighting border line of all occurrences of a selected word in Rstudio

Tags: css, rstudio

As you might already know, in Rstudio when you select a word in your script, it automatically highlights all occurrences of that word throughout your code like the "effect" word in the below image:

[image]

Now my question is: can we change the color of the highlighting border line to something else? I know there is https://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com/ website which allows you to build your customized theme however there I cannot find a variable for the color of the border line. I want to use the "Tomorrow night blue" theme but the problem is that, in Rstudio the border line's color in that theme is not great and it's hardly visible so I want to change it to white, is this possible?